# Error when trying to run tests on private pod

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I'm working on some internal pods to be used in our development processes.
This is something I've done numerous times before, and never had an issue.

Recently, I've been getting an error when trying to run the XCTests.

```
2018-03-21 12:43:22.054233+0000 xctest[63996:2843446] The bundle “<pod>_Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. 

Try reinstalling the bundle.

2018-03-21 12:43:22.054394+0000 xctest[63996:2843446] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/<#username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<#pod>-fbsbcldvjowbzzajxgzamhshhusv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<#pod>_Tests.xctest/<#pod>_Tests): 
Library not loaded: @rpath/<#pod>.framework/<#pod>
Referenced from: /Users/<#username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<#pod>-fbsbcldvjowbzzajxgzamhshhusv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<#pod>_Tests.xctest/<#pod>_Tests
Reason: image not found)

Program ended with exit code: 82
```

I should note that:

1. If I use the same code in a test app, it runs perfectly.
2. If I build the test without using any reference to my pod classes, it runs perfectly.

Can't figure out what the issue is. Looked online and found a few answers regarding `UTests` which didn't help much.

Using latest Xcode (9.2) with the latest swift (4.0.3).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if it help, but try to remove `DerivedData` folder. Close Xcode and then in console: `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` and then `rm -rf DerivedData`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.
I cleaned the project, cleaned build folder, quit Xcode, deleted derived data, restart mac... you name it.

Comment: Have you gotten these particular pods to work in a different test? Can you get other pods to work in this case?

Comment: I never tried. This is a pod I’m currently developing and I need to test it (and complete it) before pushing it and starting use. This only started happening recently. Anyone aware of issues as such around high Sierra? I know homebrew had an issue and was required to be reinstalled.

Comment: @Oren did you find the solution?

Comment: No @HussaanS. Unfortunately I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting test target's host application. Select **project** from the navigator, under **TARGETS** section select your test target and set host application,